# Server validation MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a hierarchy design with Manager, Workers and Customers.

Customers are under Workers. Workers are under Managers. So each Manager can only sees and edit its own children and grand children.

I have created a page for each manager to do this. So my question is when manager submit the edited page, do I still have to verify on server again that the edit submitted really is his children or grand children?

This seems a little tedious so I am wondering how hard is it for client to guess or spoof MongoDB Object ID? I don't want Manager1 to be able to send POST request to edit Manager2 children by specifying his own post request parameters.

Are they any specific techniques for this kind of design?

Comment: Manager,  workers and customers are all different collections??

Comment: MongoDB transactions are atomic at document level and provides isolation capability.  So,  changes made to manager1 document are completely independent of changes being made to manager2 document. Refer: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/

Comment: The chance of a technically enabled manager guessing the objectid of another manager is very small. It  is possible since the objectid is not completely random but it is very difficult since there could be any number of 10s or 10,000s or objectids between the managers

Comment: Of course only a logged ion manager should be able top change THEIR settings and only THEIR settings

Comment: "o my question is when manager submit the edited page, do I still have to verify on server again that the edit submitted really is his children or grand children?" checking such a thing client side is less than reliable